# Did the Think Tank really help the Vidiians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

The smarmy 'spokesman' of the [Think Tank](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708993/) (from the episode of the same name) claimed he and his helped find a cure for the phage. Now Voyager's a long way from Vidiian space by now and I wouldn't put lying about that past him for a second- was any material confirming or dispelling this claim published/released?

Comment: Unless contrary evidence exists, I think that claims should be considered true. Otherwise, absolutely everything can be doubted (unless it's seem occurring onscreen).

Comment: This is very nitpicky with respect to the question and thus not an answer - but strictly speaking, the line from the episode is "we found a cure for the Vidiian phage". That says nothing about whether they actually treated the Vidiians (or any significant number of them) with that cure. Merely *finding* the cure (and possibly being proud of having done so, to reconfirm their own superb intelligence) is not the same as *helping* those that would need the cure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They did

We have confirmation in the official [*The Star Trek Book*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Trek_Book) that the Vidiians were indeed cured by the Think Tank.

> *Although they were considered
> enemies by the Voyager crew, one
> of their physicians, Dr. Danara Pel,
> struck up a relationship with the
> Doctor as she worked to find a
> means of combating the disease.
> **Ultimately, a cure was found with
> the assistance of an alien thinktank that excels at problem-solving.***

Their aim in the *Voyager encounter* was to recruit (note, **not abduct**) Seven of Nine into their odd little collective. They see her as a potentially willing new member and it would hardly be sensible to make unfounded boasts to get her to join. As a member of the Think Tank she would learn of their deception in very short order, pretty much as soon as she has access to their files:

> **SEVEN:** *Why me?*
>
> **KURROS:** *I admire your humility. The collective knowledge of the Borg contained within a single mind. When we factor in your innate intelligence and the enhancements afforded you by your bionetic implants, we concluded you are an ideal candidate. The first we have recruited in seventeen years.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *When did you arrive at this assessment?*
>
> **KURROS:** *During your interview.*

---

This assessment is also confirmed in the *Official Star Trek Fact Files*

> Vidiian physiology: **This practice** [i.e. stealing organs] **is widespread
> across the Delta Quadrant up until the intervention of the 'think
> tank' group, led by Kurros, some time before 2375; a cure for the
> Phage is found, and the Vidiian culture begins the slow journey back
> to how it once was.** Many races feel great sympathy for the Vidiians
> and appreciate the horrific situation they find themselves in, but
> there is little doubt that the tactics they employed to harvest body
> parts will stay in the memories of victimized Delta Quadrant
> civilizations for many years.
>
> <sub><sup>[Official Star Trek Fact Files: File 18, Card 7b - "Vidiian Base"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Fact_Files)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah but by that token, wouldn't she have just as quickly learned they sicced those alien bounty hunters on Voyager so they could 'offer their assistance'?

Comment: @nu'daq - That's assuming they kept a recording of the conversation. I see no good reason why they'd keep that, especially if their goal was to trick Seven.

Answer (score 9):

## Possibly...but probably not

The entry on the Vidiians at the official Star Trek web site, **StarTrek.com**, makes *no mention of the phage being cured at any point* :

> A space-faring Delta Quadrant species known as educators, explorers, and above all artists — until the phage hit them two millennia ago. Thousands die each day, and organ harvesting is the only way to survive; corpses are preferred, but in an emergency they may be taken from a living body. As a consequence, their medical technology is much higher advanced than the United Federation of Planets norm, including immunogenicity. They are not familiar with holographic imaging, and their power systems may use a dilithium matrix. A honatta helps a patron find the appropriate organs. Despite the disease and lack of conscience in this area, the culture somehow goes on: Motura is a sculptor. The disease leaves them weakened, requiring slave labor to do such tasks as mining.

([Source](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/vidiians))

There is no mention of the cure, as rumour, fact, or otherwise.

Similarly, the official entry on the [phage](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/phage-the) itself does not mention a cure.  It seems that the writers intended for the truth behind Kurros' claim to be ambiguous at best.

Now consider the following points:

- There was no evidence of activity by the Think Tank when Voyager was closer to Vidiian space.  (None of the cultures encountered by Voyager had reported contact with a group of "problem solvers".)
- The Think Tank do not seem particularly mobile.
- Three years worth of *travel at high warp* had passed between Voyager's encounters with the Vidiians and meeting the Think Tank.  (In that time they had also been propelled psychically across a vast distance by Kes, and then catapulted again by an advanced alien technology — thanks @Tritium21.)

**Taking these points together, it seems unlikely that the Think Tank would have crossed paths with the Vidiians.  Given the group's advanced technology, they may have simply scanned Voyager's database and picked something that would impress Janeway — a solution to a problem that seemed unsolvable.**

As @Politank-Z points out in his answer, there are novels in which the phage is cured at a time that is compatible with Kurros' claims, but of course that is Beta material (i.e. *not canon*).

Comment: Three years of travel through transwarp conduits, being psychically propelled through space, being catapulted with alien technology... not just at high warp.

Answer (score 4):

Per [Memory-Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Vidiian),

> By the beginning of the 2380s decade, the Vidiians had rid themselves of the phage. (TNG novel: Q & A)

The Think Tank's role in this is ambiguous, at best. The encounter with The Think Tank was in 2375; The Vidiians could have found a cure not involving The Think Tank by then, but after 2000 years of The Phage, it would be a coincidence. Then again, coincidence in Star Trek is awfully common. Perhaps Klingon physiology provided the key.